# client waiting time for API android

Tags: java, c#, android, api, networking

I have android application which makes requests to API using Retrofit.
Everything is working fine but I have one concern if anyone could clarify this to me.

In android I have created a OkHttpClient as follows :

```
    private static OkHttpClient getClient() {

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    return okHttpClient;
}
```

And I'm calling the client as follows :

```
    public static IAPI getAPITest() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://***/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getClient())
            .build();

    iApi = retrofit.create(IAPI .class);
    return iApi;
}
```

So from what I understood , the client can wait for a response from the back end for 1 minute.

Now imagine I have a form that need to be submitted only once (The API will insert data to database and I don't want the data to be duplicate)
and user press save and the API is called and it's taking longer than 1 minute.

In android it will display a message saying for example ("something went wrong - try again) while in the back end the process is still going and in the end it will insert the data, right?

The problem comes when user press save again and for some reasons the response took less than 1 minute.

In conclusion the data has been submitted twice and I don't want that.

How can we avoid such situation? or it will never happen? .. Correct me if I'm wrong

Thank you.

Comment: You can send a `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` to the server, store it in a table (for example) and everytime you send a request check if that UUID already exists in the server.

Comment: @danielctf I didn't get what you mean , can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm elaborating my comment here;

Let's say you have a table in your server where you store all requests made to your server. One column must have a unique ID of each request, for example an UUID that is sent from your android device.

In your android device you put a `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` in the header/body of each request made to your server.

When the server receives the request, it'll check in the table if the received UUID matches any of the UUIDs that are in the table and if it finds one it means that this is a duplicated data and you can send a message back that the data was already inserted.

If it doesn't find any, it means is new data and the server will save that new UUID in the table as well as the information you need for your business.

Comment: sounds like a good solution! i'll try it and get back to you!